# Com uma variável global consigo guardar o nome de utilizador para ser mostrada mais a frente?

Tags: vb.net

Tenho um programa em que ao fazer login (usando um nome de utilizador que já está guardado na bd em access) consiga guardar nome de utilizador para mostrar mais a frente no "menu principal" utilizado uma label ou uma textbox. Pensei numa variável global, mas não sei se será possível assim! Ou há alguma maneira mais fácil?

Obrigado a quem ajudou!

está aqui o código do login

```
Private Sub PictureBox4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox4.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Insira o campo do utilizador", "Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        TextBox1.Focus()
    ElseIf TextBox2.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Insira a sua password para o login", "Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        TextBox2.Focus()
    Else
        Dim conLogin As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0; Data Source = E:\PAP\projeto\pap.mdb")
        Dim commLogin As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT login.password FROM login WHERE nome_util = @username AND password = @password", conLogin)
        Dim usernameParam As New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@username", Me.TextBox1.Text)
        Dim passwordParam As New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@password", Me.TextBox2.Text)

        commLogin.Parameters.Add(usernameParam)
        commLogin.Parameters.Add(passwordParam)
        commLogin.Connection.Open()

        Dim reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = commLogin.ExecuteReader()
        If reader.HasRows Then
            If TextBox1.Text = "admin" Then
                MessageBox.Show("Login feito com sucesso", "Agrowine", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                principal.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            Else
                principaluti.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Utilizador inválido!", "Agrowine", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            TextBox1.Clear()
            TextBox2.Clear()
            TextBox1.Focus()
        End If
        commLogin.Connection.Close()
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: É Windows Form?

Comment: sim sim........